# How to put all the sub array values in php variables

Tags: php, arrays

I'd like to add all the values from each sub arrays below in some distinct php variables.

I can access each value individually but I can't figure out how to put all the values from the first sub array in one variable e.g. $subarray_zero and all the values from the second sub array in another variable e.g. $subarray_one. The idea is then to use those variables to add the values in mysql, so I'll have two columns, one with all the values from the variable $subarray_zero and another column $subarray_one with all the values from the second sub array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [5] => 3.5
            [6] => 4.5
            [7] => 5.5

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [8] => 5
            [9] => 6
            [10] => 7

        )

)
```

Thanks for your help

full code

```
$period = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15);

$sma = array(6,9);

foreach ($sma as $range)    {


$sum = array_sum(array_slice($period, 0, $range));

$result = array($range - 1 => $sum / $range);


for ($i = $range, $n = count($period); $i != $n; ++$i) {

        $result[$i] = $result[$i - 1] + ($period[$i] - $period[$i - $range]) / $range;

}

$array[] = $result;


}


echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Instead of variable creations, use `foreach loop` to iterate over each sub-array and use them for saving values to db

Comment: What is that supposed to be good for? You already _have_ a way of addressing those data structures via their key, why would you need a second one …? _“The idea is then to use those variables to add the values in mysql”_ - and whether you use `$myDataArray[0]` or `$myNeedlessExtraVariable` at that point would make what difference exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$smplarr=Array(0 => Array(5 => 3.5,6 => 4.5,7 => 5.5),1 => Array(8 => 5,9 => 6,10 => 7));
            list($subarray_zero,$subarray_one)=$smplarr;
            print_r($subarray_zero);echo "<br>";
            print_r($subarray_one);
```

see output

```
Array ( [5] => 3.5 [6] => 4.5 [7] => 5.5 ) 
Array ( [8] => 5 [9] => 6 [10] => 7 )
```

Use list Thanks

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Many Thanks for your help!